# How to JOIN and get data from either table based on specific logics?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-outer-join, sql-null

Let's say I have 2 tables as shown below:

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

I want to join the 2 tables together so that the output table will have a "**date**" column, a "**hrs_billed_v1**" column from table1, and a "**hrs_billed_v2**" column from table2. Sometimes a date only exists in one of the tables, and sometimes a date exists in both tables. If a date exists in both table1 and table2, then I want to allocate the **hrs_billed_v1** from table1 and **hrs_billed_v2** from table2 to the output table.

So the ideal result will look like this:

[image]

I've tried "FULL OUTPUT JOIN" but it returned some null values for "date" in the output table. Below is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT CASE WHEN table1.date is null then table2.date WHEN table2.date is null then table1.date end as date, 
CASE WHEN table1.hrs_billed_v1 is null then 0 else table1.hrs_billed_v1 END AS hrs_billed_v1, 
CASE WHEN table2.hrs_billed_v2 is null then 0 else table2.hrs_billed_v2 END AS hrs_billed_v2
FROM table1         
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.common = table2.common
```

Note that the "common" column where I use to join table1 and table2 on is just a constant string that exists in both tables.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `DISTINCT CASE WHEN table1.date is null then table2.date WHEN table2.date is null then table1.date end as date` can be replaced with `coalesce(table1.date, table2.date) AS date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `full join` is indeed what you want. I think that would be:

```
select 
    common,
    date,
    coalesce(t1.hrs_billed_v1, 0) as hrs_billed_v1,
    coalesce(t2.hrs_billed_v2, 0) as hrs_billed_v2
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 using (common, date)
```

Rationale:

- you don't show what `common` is; your data indicates that you want to match rows of the same date - so I put both in the join condition; you might need to adapat that
- there should really be no need for `distinct`
- `coalesce()` is much shorter than the `case` expressions
- `using ()` is handy to express the join condition when the columns to match have the same name in both tables

Comment: Thanks, @GMB. The problem is sometimes a Date only exists in one table, not both. In those cases, I still want to put that information into the output table.

Comment: @Stanleyrr: that's exactly what the `full join` does.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, I will use coalesce(table1.date, table2.date) as date, because sometimes a date will exist in only 1 of the tables. So the coalesce function can ensure I get either value from either table.

Comment: @Stanleyrr: the `full join` allows missing rows from both tables. For example when a row in `t1` has no match in `t2`, it still shows up in the resultset, with values from `t2` having `null` values.  `coalesce()` is there to turn `null` values to `0`.

Comment: Thanks, @GMB. But I can't do "select date from ..." because the query will ask me to specify which table to select the date column from. That's why I had to do "coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) as date".

Comment: @Stanleyrr: in general, you are correct. But here, we use `using ()` in the join condition. This eliminates the ambiguity, as explained in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html): *Furthermore, the output of JOIN USING suppresses redundant columns*